Making a Post Request to Google Maps Places API (New) with Python
I am trying to retrieve data from google's 'NEW' Places API for google maps, specifically the New Nearby Search API. I have a working API Key (well it works with the old Places API, I don't believe i need a new one) I am trying a JSON Post Request because apparently most of the New APIs only accept JSON Post requests and no longer accept URL requests. I have found several good examples of making Post Requests with Python on the web, but zero of them are accessing Google Maps APIs. Below is my code example. I believe it is reaching the API server, but returns a 400 code (below).
[DEBUG  ] [Starting new HTTPS connection (1)] places.googleapis.com:443
[DEBUG  ] [https          ]//places.googleapis.com:443 "POST /v1/places:searchNearby HTTP/1.1" 400 None
<Response [400]>
I have tried several variations of this code, including inserting my API Key directly instead of using a variable.
from kivymd.app import MDApp

import requests
import json



class MyApp(MDApp):
    api_file = open("Maps_API.txt", "r")
    API_KEY = api_file.read()
    api_file.close()

       
    url = "https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchNearby"
    data = {"includedTypes": ["gas_station"],"maxResultCount": 10,
            "locationRestriction": {
                "circle": {
                    "center": {
                        "latitude": 31.06114,
                        "longitude": -98.17896},
                    "radius": 500.0}}}
    
    
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json","X-Goog-Api-Key": API_KEY,"X-Goog-FieldMask": "id,displayName,location"}


    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.post(url, data=json_data, headers=headers)
        

    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        print(data)
            
    
MyApp().run()


Haven't tested your code, but if you are posting JSON you probably should use json instead of data in requests.post - See here for more details.

Thank you, but, same response 400. I think i tried every combination on the link you provided.

Found the Answer!
How to call via Google places API(New) Text Search (ID Only) in python?
Boils down to the Field Mask format was wrong.  Needed "places.id,places.displayName,places.location" not just "id,displayName,location"
